# Merging Vertices not working after separating faces using "P"?

Tags: faces

I am trying to merge two vertices. Earlier on in my modeling I hit "P" to create a new part/object ( I origallny did this to keep that part flat ). Now I need to rejoin some vertices as there's a small gap but "Merge" - "Merge to center" does not work. As always any suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks, Jack.
[image]

Comment: If you have separated your 2 meshes in 2 separate objects, you can't join their vertices anymore, is it your problem here?

Comment: Yes this is my issue.

Comment: so the answer is: don't separate your 2 meshes into 2 objects  ^^

Comment: Yeah ok. So how do I Un-seperate them?

Comment: You need to join the 2 objects with Ctrl J, then you'll be able to create edges between the vertices

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting all the vertices that border the gap

[image]

and press 'F' to fill the gap.
[image: 2]

As your description was pretty complicated, it might be helpful to paste an image in your question! :)

Comment: You can't Fill between seperate objects!

Comment: Picture added. As you can see it's only a thin gap I'm wanting to close. Hence the need for merging.

Comment: I posted this without knowing that it was two different objects, yes you would select the two objects and use Ctrl J to join them, then use the fill

Comment: I have tried Ctrl J and then merge the vertices but still with no success.